# Extract formula terms using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that will help me extract terms in a formula that begin with a function and are within brackets.

For example, say I have the following formula:

```
formula <- formula(cured ~ dur(duration) + age + sex + duranduran)
```

I can extract the individual terms:

```
attr(terms(formula), "term.labels")
```

which returns the vector

```
[1] "dur(duration)" "age"          "sex"          "duranduran"
```

I want to use `grep` with some regex to give the index of any terms that are enclosed by `dur()`. So far, I have tried

```
grep("^dur", attr(terms(formula), "term.labels"))
```

but this doesn't take into account the brackets. It returns 1 and 4, as the terms `dur(duration)` and `duranduran` both start with `dur`. I am looking for a regular expression for:

Begins with `dur(`, AND ends with `)`.

Comment: Do you mean `grep("^dur\\(.*\\)$", attr(terms(formula), "term.labels"))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
grep("^dur\\(.*\\)$", attr(terms(formula), "term.labels"))
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `dur` - `dur` substring
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WbORTA/1).

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want with the package **stringr** and assuming that you want to extract terms that always have `dur()` as the target function.

Let me know if you want to generalize it.

```r
library(stringr)
formula <- formula(cured ~ dur(duration) + age + sex + duranduran)

elements = attr(terms(formula), "term.labels")
idx = str_which(elements, "^dur\\(\\w+\\)")
idx
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This does it without regular expressions.  First get the labels and then using startsWith/endsWith we have the following.  Omit `which` if a logical vector is ok as the result.

```
labs <- labels(terms(formula))
which(startsWith(labs, "dur(") & endsWith(labs, ")"))
```

### Note

The input equivalent and simplified from question:

```
formula <- cured ~ dur(duration) + age + sex + duranduran
```